# Usable content addressable storage (like git or nix)

Tags: git, filesystems, nix, content-addressable-storage

Is there any piece of software which you can use purely as a content addressable filesystem, for say the `/home/user` folder?

Lately I've been diving into Nix and git a little bit, and I got interested in the usage of content addressable file systems. Primarily I like the idea of having a store that holds all objects, and then creating a view on this set of objects. In git by checking out a branch, which populates the working directory with a view on the store. In nix by (i believe) checking out a generation which creates a view on a set of packages which you can use.

So what I mean is that there is a store of all my files available, but I can use a tool to switch between different views on this set of files. I believe this could be very helpful for creating a workflow in which I have at any time a view on the set of files which are relevant at that moment.

Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: [Along similar lines, but more far-reaching, if you'll pardon the pun...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_File_System)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes I've seen IPFS. It's a great idea, yet a little too far-reaching for my purposes. I'm mainly looking for a tool which I can use to quickly switch between different views on a set of files on my machine. Distributed or remote would be an extra, however the main use case I'm seeking to try is to "switch between views of files". Mainly to keep my views clean and relevant to what I'm working on.

Comment: "*…quickly switch between different views on a set of files…*" Isn't it just any version control? Why not just Git?

Comment: Yeah I agree that is indeed very similar to git. However git has been optimized for code, not large files and binaries. I'm thinking about using something which I could use for e.g, my entire home folder. This would include binaries, large files, and probably also a set of git repositories.

Comment: Not content-addressable at all, but you might consider ZFS and snapshots.

Comment: To follow up, I'm currently considering using `ostree` for this use case. It's not necessarily made for it, but seems like it might work